# Set of checkboxes to act like radio buttons

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am able to create set of checkboxes and toggle between them like radio button. But When I click on a different set, the previous set checked option gets disabled. Can anyone guide where I am going wrong. Thank you.

```
    //set1
    <li class="dropdown-item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="InchMm" data-id=0>
        <label for="unit1">Inch</label>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="InchMm" data-id=1 checked>
        <label for="unit2">Mm/label>
    </li> 

   <hr/>

   //set2
   <li class="dropdown-item">
     <input type="checkbox" id="Temp" data-id=2>
     <label for="unit3">Fh</label>
   </li>

   <li class="dropdown-item">
     <input type="checkbox" id="Temp" data-id=3 checked>
     <label for="unit4">Cl</label>
   </li>
```

Comment: why don't you use jquerys onchange like on the sample fiddle you gave? Also there is a big problem with your code, ids are unique, you can't have multiple elements with the same id, the sample fiddle you provided uses class instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed id for class, ids are unique, you can't have multiple elements with the same id so you can use class instead if you want to target multiple elements

### ID

The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

```
    <li class="dropdown-item">
        <input type="checkbox" class="InchMm" data-id=0>
        <label for="unit1">Inch</label>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
        <input type="checkbox" class="InchMm" data-id=1 checked>
        <label for="unit2">Mm</label>
    </li> 

   <hr/>

   <li class="dropdown-item">
     <input type="checkbox" class="Temperature" data-id=2>
     <label for="unit3">Farenhiet</label>
   </li>

   <li class="dropdown-item">
     <input type="checkbox" class="Temperature" data-id=3 checked>
     <label for="unit4">Celsuis</label>
   </li>
```

Now you can use separate onchange for each set of checkboxes

```
// Inch to Mm
$(".InchMm").change(function(){
   $(".InchMm").prop('checked',false);
   $(this).prop('checked',true);

   
 });
                                  
                                  
//Farenhiet to celsius                                   
$(".Temperature").change(function(){
  $(".Temperature").prop('checked',false);
  $(this).prop('checked',true);

  
});
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Should have used class. Thank you.